# how to deal with permissions, roles and user roles table for access control level management in php

Tags: php, mysql

hello i am i implementing access control level management in one of my project. but problem is that i am little bit confused for what kind of data i need to insert in permission table. for example if i am going to manage the acl for menu and submenu then how i will manage acl on my table and which formatted data i need to insert. becouse actuly i am going to insert the json formatted data in my permission and the json data will reperesent all permissions for roles.this is my array and i going to convert it into the json and will insert into the database but not sure wheather its correct way or not.

```
Array
(
    [create] => Array
        (
            [mymenu] => 1
            [Additional] => 1
            [Application 2] => 1
            [mymenu] => 1

        )

    [view] => Array
        (
            [mymenu] => 1
            [mymenu] => 1
            [Report] => 1
            [Additional] => 1


    [update] => Array
        (
            [mymenu] => 1
            [Application] => 1
            [Report] => 1

        )

    [delete] => Array
        (
            [mymenu] => 1
            [mymenu] => 1
            [mymenu] => 1

        )

)
```